# Intermittent "Temporary lookup failure" Postfix error

Tags: postfix-mta

We have noticed in our Postfix log a lot of error `Temporary lookup failure`. They seem to appear randomly. These errors did happen on well-known domains like gmail.com so it shouldn't be related to DNS issue.

Here's how it looks like:

```
Dec 16 02:44:15 prod2 postfix/smtpd[15673]: NOQUEUE: reject: 
RCPT from mx1.example.com[1.2.3.4]: 451 4.3.0 <example@gmail.com>:
Temporary lookup failure; from=<transactional@example.com> 
to=<example@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[172.17.0.7]>
```

We haven't found any pattern for now so any idea on what might go wrong is helpful!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Facing the same issue :/

Comment: I'm getting this too after moving the same mail config from an Ubuntu 18.04 to a 22.04 machine. I suspect it's something to do with systemd resolve but don't know what.

Answer (score -1):

The message means that `postfix` on the server `prod2` is unable to lookup some of its tables (like `aliases` or similar) due to them being out of sync with hashmaps (corresponding `.db` files) or due to incorrect values in the tables. Check your `postfix` logs for other warnings.

Comment: Thanks. Postfix is used for sending out emails (outbound) and doesn't have any alias system. The error also happens randomly.